# Suggestions on how to handle a static response with dynamic session data

Tags: ajax, caching, optimization, static, comet

Imagine a website that is highly cached where the output of almost every GET action is cached into a html file that is accessible directly from the HTTP server without having to perform a server-side CGI operation. Now imagine that in addition to that, JavaScript is used to filter the response of the HTML request using AJAX. The AJAX response contains only the appropriate response of the page (so for standard HTML pages it will contain everything except for the surrounding layout, for modals it will contain only the modal box HTML, etc...).

Now lets imagine that the HTML content may be cached neutrally (when nobody is logged in) or cached for someone who is logged in. There are certain areas of the page that are tied to session data (like the welcome message, the profile link, etc...) and that data is specific to the session. But since we're using JavaScript, we can buffer the AJAX response, change the session element values, and then stick it into the DOM all the while the user is unaware of any session hot swapping. This relies ofcoarse only on GET requests and pages where the actual content is not 100% session dependent.

Now here is my question. If I were to implement this (and trust me I will) then how might I actually keep track of the session activity while the user is browsing the page? With a traditional server-side operation, whenever the user accesses a page then the server-side framework will update the session and keep tabs on the session-related variables. With a static HTTP request operation then all server-side involvement is avoided. So I will need to figure out some way of keeping track of what's going on with the session; here are my approaches:

**1) Perform two AJAX requests (or an additional one when needed):**
Once the user queries a page then the contents will be downloaded as static HTML. But at the same time that page is queried then another AJAX request will be serviced to a session-specific URL/server updating/querying the status of the session. This can be done side by side or can be performed after every few requests are made.

Pros = HTML files are left unchanged, HTML files can be set to have a ETag or future expires header, JavaScript can cache only the static HTML and use it for offline browsing, a session-server can be dedicated, optimized and configured for session activity.
Cons = Two AJAX requests are performed, excessive polling for potentially redundant data, session handling made be separated from content server.

**2) Use a midway proxy that appends the session-data as a trailing session JSON**
A request is made to the server. There is a proxy in between that locally accesses the session data and then performs another HTTP request (either locally or remotely) which is then concatenated with the session data findings fetched just before. The browser is responded with a clean copy of HTML code where has JavaScript-specific session content and then everything is updated at the same moment.

Pros = Everything is downloaded at once, only one connection required, works like a normal HTTP request would
Cons = Caching gets difficult when a dynamic content proxy is used, content-length may need to be search and replaced with to append additional data, may not work with some browsers?

**3) Use Comet for session data**
A persistant, reverse-AJAX comet connection could be established at the start of the website connection. Then, all static-HTML requests could be accessed normally. All session-related requests could be accessed from the comet connection.

Pros = Separation of static content and dynamic content.
Cons = Comet isn't supported very well and doesn't work very well, server latency, may conflict with same origin policy.

How do you guys think this problem should be solved? Do you think its doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is to use **templated data** and **dynamic data** separate from each other. It's too much work and too messy to implement this on your own so you can go as far as using a MVC framework to provide JSON requests with templating (AngularJS, KnockoutJS, EmbedJS, etc...) or you can just stick to using templates in general. Keep in mind that this destroys SEO.